# Transition on flip effect keeps background visible. How to fix?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a flip effect when a box is hovered which will transition to a full gray box without the visible background (front side). So that means that it's supposed to start as a blank box with only color on it.

[GitHub with source code](https://github.com/PillowGR2K/ProjectKNE)
[website](https://pillowgr2k.github.io/ProjectKNE/characters.html)

`backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).